# Reloaded rvm 3.0.0 reinstalled bundle, now getting undefined method in action view:template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-6

Background: I am trying to generated a user guided list, where the user is allowed to make two selections (a store and a buyer).  The table that holds the list does not have the buyer's name but does have a store_id that points to the store.  The buyer's name is developed from a third table.

This code worked fine before I had to uninstall rails-3.0.0 from rvm.  After reinstall and doing bundle install, this simple_form form-inline code started throwing the error shown in the log below:

the code that worked in the list.html.erb file:

```
<%= simple_form_for :search, url: list_path, method: "GET", html: { class: 'form-inline' } do |f| %><br>
    <%= f.input :id, collection: @stores, label: false  %></td><br>
    <td><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :buyer, @buyers, :buyer, :buyer, include_blank: true %><br>
    </td><td>
     <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %><br>
<% end %>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

The arrays @store and @buyer are generated in the shop controller in the def list stanza.  Shown here:

```
  def list
      @search = params["search"]
      logger.debug "\n\n#{@search}.inspect\n\n"
      @lists = Shop.get_my_list(params["search"])
      
          @elists = Shop.find_by_sql("select distinct S.vendor, S.item, S.cnt, S.coupon from SHOPS AS S left join MUPCs as M on m.item = s.item WHERE M.ID IS NULL")

          @buyers = Shop.find_by_sql("select distinct buyer, buyer from mupcs")

  end
```

Log generated:

```
Started GET "/list?search%5Bid%5D=1&search%5Bbuyer%5D=&commit=Submit" for 10.0.0.3 at 2021-01-15 21:24:15 -0800<br>
Processing by ShopsController#list as HTML
  Parameters: {"search"=>{"id"=>"1", "buyer"=>""}, "commit"=>"Submit"}<br>
  Shop Load (0.2ms)  select id, name from Stores<br>
  ↳ app/controllers/shops_controller.rb:7:in `get_stores'
  Shop Load (0.2ms)  select distinct location from Mupcs<br>
  ↳ app/controllers/shops_controller.rb:8:in `get_stores'


{"id"=>"1", "buyer"=>""}.inspect




inside get_my_list |1|


  Shop Load (0.2ms)  <br>select distinct m.buyer, m.location, s.vendor, s.item, s.cnt, s.coupon, s.store_id from shops as s,  mupcs as m where m.item = s.item and s.store_id = 1 order by m.buyer, m.location<br>
  ↳ app/models/shop.rb:54:in `get_my_list'
  Shop Load (0.2ms)  <br>select distinct S.vendor, S.item, S.cnt, S.coupon from SHOPS AS S left join MUPCs as M on m.item = s.item WHERE M.ID IS NULL<br>
  ↳ app/controllers/shops_controller.rb:36:in `list'
  Shop Load (0.2ms)  <br>select distinct buyer, buyer from mupcs<br>
  ↳ app/controllers/shops_controller.rb:38:in `list'<br>
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb<br>
  Rendering shops/list.html.erb within layouts/application<br>
  Rendered shops/list.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 5.2ms | Allocations: 4177)<br>
  Rendered layout<br> layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 5.4ms | Allocations: 4246)<br>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms | Allocations: 7511)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for #<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"1", "buyer"=>""} permitted: false>):
     7: <tr>
     8: <td valign="top">
     9: <%= simple_form_for :search, url: list_path, method: "GET", html: { class: 'form-inline' } do |f| %>
    10:     <%= f.input :id, collection: @stores, label: false  %></td>
    11:     <td>
    12:     <%= f.collection_select :buyer, @buyers, :buyer, :buyer, include_blank: true %>
    13:     </td><td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix. I had to create a new private whitelist and change the name of the in-line from "search" to "genlist" but now it seems to work.